# Is it fine to call two different Services from a single method in a @Controller class in Spring?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have two separate `@Service` annotated classes, which I need to call in a single `@GetMapping` annotated method in a `@RestController` annotated class.

Is this a bad practice?

Something like the following example:

*UserService.java*

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public User findById(Long id) throws UserNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findOne(id);
        if (user != null) return user;

        throw new UserNotFoundException("The ID " + id + " doesn't behave to any user!");
    }

}
```

*PostService.java*

```
@Service
public class PostService {

    @Autowired
    PostRepository postRepository;

    public List <Post> findPostsByUserId(Long userId) {
        return postRepository.findByUserId(userId);
    }

}
```

*UserController.java*

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private PostService postService;

    @GetMapping("/users/{id}/posts")
    public ResponseEntity <List <Post>> retrieveAllPostsByUserId(@PathVariable("id") Long userId)
    throws UserNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.findById(userId);
        if (user != null) {
            List <Post> posts = postService.findPostsByUserId(userId);

            return new ResponseEntity <List<Post>>(posts, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        throw new UserNotFoundException("The ID " + userId + " doesn't behave to any user!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Sure, that's fine. They are independent services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this should be fine and actually a good practice.
In case of update to two Repositories (not in this case), just be aware of transaction boundaries.

But in this specific case you have unnecessarily complicated your code.

For example UserService.findById does not return null and throws exception.
But in your controller code you check for null and when it is not null you throw exception. This is redundant.

In your specific case just calling postService.findPostsByUserId should be sufficient. Returning an empty list for non-existing user should be ok.
Most probably the client is visiting /users/123/posts after visiting /users/123, so extra check of user existence may not be needed.